# Create a loop with fractions increasing from 0.01 till 0.99

Tags: r

I want to create a for loop that goes from 0.01 till 0.99, but I don't know how to go about it.

```
for(i in 0.01:0.99)
```

This will only give me the outcomes for 0.01 and 0.99. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `seq`

```
i1 <- seq(0.01, 0.99, by = 0.01)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to create such sequence

```
(1:99)/100
```

but I think `seq` method mentioned by @akrun is a more formal fashion to make it